# C#/WPF: Print a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, printing

Does anyone have an idea how to Print (A4) the Content of a ListView (e.g. with all the ColumnHeaders, fit to the Page-Width and without the Scrollbar)? I've found several old threads about this on stackoverflow, but no complete answer.

Thank you.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone asked on msdn and it looks like you need to [create a Fixed Document, loop over the ListView datasouce and build the table cells and rows in the created document.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4ac4c90d-61a9-4988-85e0-6437bcaae6d8/)

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/31ed1875-728d-4037-9074-4eba5c821311/wpf-report-engine-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If God forbid you need to do this in 2019:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

//TaskViewModel.Tasks is the collection (List<> in my case) your ListView takes data from
            foreach (var item in TaskViewModel.Tasks)            {
                fd.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(item.ToString()))); //you may need to create a ToString method in your type, if it's string it's ok
            }

            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            if (pd.ShowDialog() != true) return;

            fd.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
            fd.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;

            IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = fd as IDocumentPaginatorSource;

            pd.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Flow Document...");
        }
```

Credit for part of the code:
http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2012/06/printing-flow-document-using-wpf.html